# How to change language version in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, c#-6.0, nameof

I want to use the `nameof` operator in my C# project in Visual Studio 2015 but the compiler complains with the following message.

> Feature 'nameof operator' is not available in C# 5. Please use
>   language version 6 or greater.

I want to know how I can change the C# language version from Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: The same way you change language version in Visual Studio 2013 FYI

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Try this..

**Project -> Properties -> Build  -> Advanced -> Language Version**

Comment: How to change the version in a solution with a vb.net website project?

Answer (score 54):

Go to **Project** → **Properties** → **Build** → **Advanced** → **Language Version** → **OK** as shown with detail steps and screen shots below:

Follow these steps to change the language version of your project

1: Open your project with Visual Studio 2012, 2013 or 2015, click on **View** from Menu and then click on **Solution Explorer**

[image]

2: From **Solution Explorer**, Right Click on the project and **Properties** from context menu

[image]

3: From properties dialog, select the tab **Build** and click on **Advanced** button

[image]

4: Now, from **Advanced Build Settings** dialog, select **Language Version** and click **OK** button. Thats it.

[image]