# How to Update Version from Earlier Versions of Visual Studio to 2017?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have a number of projects created in earlier version of Visual Studio.  These open fine in 2017, I can edit and save changes, but the solution file still has the icon indicating they are VB10, VB11 or VB14 solutions.

My concern is that in later versions of Visual Studio the solutions will no longer be supported.  Can I force a complete upgrade to Visual Studio 2017? Is this necessary?

Comment: Yes you can update with version 15.3.4 of VS 2017

Comment: For one, you can hand-edit the project file and set the tool version and the language version to the one you need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32122660/how-to-change-the-vb-net-language-version-in-visual-studio-2015 Me not being a Vb guy, I do not know if there is a UI element to achieve this.

Comment: I don't think it's necessary. Future versions of Visual Studio will probably support these solutions for a long time.