# CS0103: The name 'WebApiConfig' does not exist in the current context deployed in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have a project in asp .net mvc that has web api , deployed it in one of our servers and working fine. but when we deployed it in another server, I got this error. I have tried a lot of things  but none worked. Our project is deployed by publishing it (project>righ clik>publish) so I only copy 4 files into the \wwwroot folders which are:
*bin, db, global.asax, web.config* files. inside bin is roslyn, I needed to emphasize this as I am suspecting this is the reason, but can not see any solution except for it doesn't work in .net 4.0, so I had to upgrade to 4.6.1 framework which did not work. Also, it seems like it's not detecting that it has been upgraded already ( as per the error below)

what I can remember I did (from lots of things)
1. modify a lot in web.config ex. removing the  ..
2. changed target framework to recent upgrad
3. modify global.asax and .cs
4. I also added a new folder App_start where I put the WebApiConfig.cs, although in the other server (where it is working), I did not have to do this.
5. changed the application pool to point to the upgraded .net framework, and made sure it is in applicationidentity.
6. a lot of thread suggested to upgrade or add webhost dll which I already have in the bin, and most were in a scenario where the dev is loading it in the solution, whereas this one is already deployed in IIS so there's no nuget or whatsoever.
7. clear temp folder in c: windows, and microsoft.net temp folder
8. refresh/reload IIS

etc etc... but none worked.

any suggestion that might help me lead to solution?

here is the exact error:

```
c:\windows\system32\inetsrv> "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\csc.exe" /t:library /utf8output /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.DataSetExtensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\77b0ae5a\400bc18f\assembly\dl3\d7e5bbcd\c741ebed_9e59cd01\Google.GData.Photos.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\77b0ae5a\400bc18f\assembly\dl3\3ada5bef\858605d1_9e59cd01\obout_Flyout2_NET.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\77b0ae5a\400bc18f\assembly\dl3\15fa91af\6fd4a44e_db53d401\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\77b0ae5a\400bc18f\assembly\dl3\783ef7e0\00e77289_2fd1ce01\log4net.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Web.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\77b0ae5a\400bc18f\assembly\dl3\ef2440b3\00bf3b7d_32a4cd01\Lucene.Net.Contrib.Highlighter.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\77b0ae5a\400bc18f\assembly\dl3\e8c90713\fa78514e_db53d401\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Design\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Design.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\77b0ae5a\400bc18f\assembly\dl3\f2da8d7f\806fddac_7dfbce01\mysql.data.entity.EF6.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.WorkflowServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.WorkflowServices.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\77b0ae5a\400bc18f\assembly\dl3\88c91bba\884912c8_9e59cd01\obout_Splitter2_Net.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\77b0ae5a\400bc18f\assembly\dl3\a220baeb\5539b0d0_9e59cd01\obout_Grid_NET.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\77b0ae5a\400bc18f\assembly\dl3\d2640883\480f9e66_db53d401\EntityFramework.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\77b0ae5a\400bc18f\assembly\dl3\078f86a2\00b1a533_a4d2cf01\ClosedXML.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Activities\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Activities.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\77b0ae5a\400bc18f\assembly\dl3\156febdd\6c174f4e_db53d401\System.Web.Helpers.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\77b0ae5a\400bc18f\assembly\dl3\c7fa927f\029f49d7_9e59cd01\obout_ComboBox.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\77b0ae5a\400bc18f\assembly\dl3\3861afbf\80bb18a8_7dfbce01\mysql.web.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\77b0ae5a\400bc18f\assembly\dl3\00d81885\dce75bbe_dccece01\AjaxControlToolkit.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\77b0ae5a\400bc18f\assembly\dl3\761adc9e\6acafcc2_9e59cd01\obout_Tree_DB_Net.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\77b0ae5a\400bc18f\assembly\dl3\7600ad82\c28a29d8_da53d401\SimpleInjector.Integration.Wcf.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Extensions.Design\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Extensions.Design.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\77b0ae5a\400bc18f\assembly\dl3\5664c916\00e77289_2fd1ce01\PayPalCoreSDK.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\77b0ae5a\400bc18f\assembly\dl3\eba09d70\de2133d6_9e59cd01\obout_Calendar2_Net.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\77b0ae5a\400bc18f\App_GlobalResources.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\77b0ae5a\400bc18f\assembly\dl3\fa759ad6\c570d7d8_9e59cd01\obout_AJAXPage.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\77b0ae5a\400bc18f\assembly\dl3\68eaa9ce\b1f0a549_db53d401\System.Web.Http.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\77b0ae5a\400bc18f\assembly\dl3\8e74aec5\d7c937c2_9e59cd01\obout_Window_NET.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\77b0ae5a\400bc18f\assembly\dl3\54dc7da5\7d9c3ce1_9e59cd01\Obout.Ajax.UI.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\77b0ae5a\400bc18f\assembly\dl3\a71099b8\dce75bbe_dccece01\AjaxMin.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\77b0ae5a\400bc18f\assembly\dl3\665f84d1\3dae83fb_9e59cd01\BlogEngine.Core.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\77b0ae5a\400bc18f\assembly\dl3\565106b1\dce75bbe_dccece01\HtmlAgilityPack.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\77b0ae5a\400bc18f\assembly\dl3\051f7cdf\b3119dd9_da53d401\SimpleInjector.Integration.WebApi.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\77b0ae5a\400bc18f\assembly\dl3\76102dab\5f3ac652_db53d401\CommonServiceLocator.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\77b0ae5a\400bc18f\assembly\dl3\7d41e83d\00e9db5a_5dfcca01\ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Activities\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Activities.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.DynamicData\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.DynamicData.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\77b0ae5a\400bc18f\assembly\dl3\762814fb\80e849a9_7dfbce01\mysql.data.entity.EF5.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\77b0ae5a\400bc18f\assembly\dl3\8f2ff8c0\612971e2_9e59cd01\Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\77b0ae5a\400bc18f\assembly\dl3\8b0d13cf\8b0493ef_9e59cd01\Google.GData.Client.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Serialization\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\77b0ae5a\400bc18f\assembly\dl3\59193b3e\03b8bba0_702cd301\itextsharp.xmlworker.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\77b0ae5a\400bc18f\assembly\dl3\88d8cd08\4d3be0ef_9e59cd01\FredCK.FCKeditorV2.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\77b0ae5a\400bc18f\assembly\dl3\9e58a3a8\9a5d8076_7b93d401\WorldLibraryDashboardAPI.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\77b0ae5a\400bc18f\assembly\dl3\356e7a50\d0495d48_db53d401\System.Web.Mvc.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\77b0ae5a\400bc18f\assembly\dl3\af32ece6\002580a7_7dfbce01\MySql.Data.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\77b0ae5a\400bc18f\assembly\dl3\f52e16e6\9fc64f9f_702cd301\itextsharp.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Extensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Extensions.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\77b0ae5a\400bc18f\assembly\dl3\3c676f90\9da349e2_9e59cd01\Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\77b0ae5a\400bc18f\assembly\dl3\ba328c56\c28a29d8_da53d401\SimpleInjector.Integration.Web.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\77b0ae5a\400bc18f\assembly\dl3\7ee77169\79b0f8c5_9e59cd01\obout_SuperForm.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration.Install\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.Install.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\77b0ae5a\400bc18f\assembly\dl3\16fae4f1\85191de5_9e59cd01\Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\77b0ae5a\400bc18f\assembly\dl3\98886566\43b378b1_db53d401\Newtonsoft.Json.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\77b0ae5a\400bc18f\assembly\dl3\43ad07eb\0f25309b_db53d401\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\77b0ae5a\400bc18f\assembly\dl3\bb169c22\ebeeca4e_db53d401\System.Web.WebPages.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\77b0ae5a\400bc18f\assembly\dl3\e69170d1\7c6971c9_9e59cd01\obout_Show_Net.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\77b0ae5a\400bc18f\App_Code.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\77b0ae5a\400bc18f\assembly\dl3\5371cd74\051ef5d5_da53d401\Mehdime.Entity.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\77b0ae5a\400bc18f\assembly\dl3\a130811d\bc8671cb_9e59cd01\obout_ListBox.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\77b0ae5a\400bc18f\assembly\dl3\f1c6c585\0e4b9966_db53d401\EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\77b0ae5a\400bc18f\assembly\dl3\65103310\964d98de_9e59cd01\NHunspell.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Services\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.Services.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\77b0ae5a\400bc18f\assembly\dl3\16a04fa5\8174c848_db53d401\System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\77b0ae5a\400bc18f\assembly\dl3\fc8cd490\00e77289_2fd1ce01\RestApiSDK.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\77b0ae5a\400bc18f\assembly\dl3\e1d12636\9901f74f_db53d401\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\77b0ae5a\400bc18f\assembly\dl3\b52ee4fa\22270db3_45ccce01\HtmlSanitizationLibrary.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.CSharp\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.CSharp.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\77b0ae5a\400bc18f\assembly\dl3\a06bca6f\00db20a4_6dd8c701\ThoughtWorks.QRCode.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\77b0ae5a\400bc18f\assembly\dl3\b5b50e6b\f4452b48_db53d401\System.Web.Http.Cors.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.ApplicationServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\77b0ae5a\400bc18f\assembly\dl3\218b39f9\18b4a6e7_9e59cd01\Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Management\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Management.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\77b0ae5a\400bc18f\assembly\dl3\342ea22d\b08cb9e3_9e59cd01\Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\77b0ae5a\400bc18f\assembly\dl3\78248b17\1c7a4548_db53d401\System.Linq.Dynamic.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\77b0ae5a\400bc18f\assembly\dl3\da11fe02\e6f1e837_416bd401\AutoMapper.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\77b0ae5a\400bc18f\assembly\dl3\44007866\2b6d11e1_9e59cd01\Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\77b0ae5a\400bc18f\assembly\dl3\3a36146b\fab257cd_9e59cd01\obout_Interface.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\77b0ae5a\400bc18f\assembly\dl3\f317f20f\d8cc2dc1_5a52ce01\Lucene.Net.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\77b0ae5a\400bc18f\assembly\dl3\742c6906\00a0477a_8becd301\System.ValueTuple.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\77b0ae5a\400bc18f\assembly\dl3\ccb8df12\eb88ecee_9e59cd01\Google.GData.Extensions.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.ServiceModel.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\77b0ae5a\400bc18f\assembly\dl3\cff9ea9a\9f5e6fd8_9e59cd01\obout_ASPTreeView_2_NET.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Activation\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Activation.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\77b0ae5a\400bc18f\assembly\dl3\75ff210f\c1936b48_db53d401\System.Web.Razor.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\77b0ae5a\400bc18f\assembly\dl3\309f5ff4\7576ca5d_9e59cd01\Yedda.Twitter.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\77b0ae5a\400bc18f\assembly\dl3\f1db8db5\b3119dd9_da53d401\SimpleInjector.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\77b0ae5a\400bc18f\assembly\dl3\e6e6d3af\fd392efb_9e59cd01\App_Licenses.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\77b0ae5a\400bc18f\assembly\dl3\5526462a\0f3421ca_9e59cd01\obout_SlideMenu3_Pro_NET.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\77b0ae5a\400bc18f\assembly\dl3\aa66042c\e10d98e7_9e59cd01\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\77b0ae5a\400bc18f\assembly\dl3\c3f516a1\a845eedf_9e59cd01\Microsoft.Web.Mvc.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\77b0ae5a\400bc18f\assembly\dl3\df934de0\b8da6c71_29ddcf01\DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.IdentityModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.IdentityModel.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.Linq.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\77b0ae5a\400bc18f\assembly\dl3\f6e58cea\d5202448_db53d401\System.Web.Cors.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\77b0ae5a\400bc18f\assembly\dl3\829f7a2e\3589f8cd_9e59cd01\obout_ImageZoom_NET.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\77b0ae5a\400bc18f\assembly\dl3\0eaa138f\c28a29d8_da53d401\SimpleInjector.Integration.Web.Mvc.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\77b0ae5a\400bc18f\assembly\dl3\7b2d7e59\7c12814c_db53d401\System.Web.Http.WebHost.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\77b0ae5a\400bc18f\assembly\dl3\6568310c\d880b8c6_9e59cd01\obout_TextMenu.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\77b0ae5a\400bc18f\assembly\dl3\9448846c\6d90f0bf_9e59cd01\SubSonic.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\77b0ae5a\400bc18f\assembly\dl3\b1854313\286853d2_9e59cd01\obout_EasyMenu_Pro.dll" /out:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\77b0ae5a\400bc18f\App_global.asax.dll" /D:DEBUG /debug+ /optimize- /w:4 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701;612;618 /warnaserror-  "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\77b0ae5a\400bc18f\App_global.asax.0.cs" "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\77b0ae5a\400bc18f\App_global.asax.1.cs" "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\77b0ae5a\400bc18f\App_global.asax.2.cs"


Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 4.6.1586.0

for C# 5
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.



This compiler is provided as part of the Microsoft (R) .NET Framework, but only supports language versions up to C# 5, which is no longer the latest version. For compilers that support newer versions of the C# programming language, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=533240

d:\wwwroot\out_wpl\Controls\Global.asax.cs(28,34): error CS0103: The name 'WebApiConfig' does not exist in the current context
```

here is part of my global.asax.cs

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
            string filePath = Server.MapPath("~/XmlDb/Site/Config/SiteConfig.xml");
            dsSites = new DataSet("sites");
            dsSites.ReadXml(filePath);
            dtSites = dsSites.Tables[0];



            var container = DependencyInjectionConfig.CreateContainer();
            container.Verify(SimpleInjector.VerificationOption.VerifyAndDiagnose);
            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new SimpleInjectorDependencyResolver(container));
            SimpleInjectorServiceHostFactory.SetContainer(container);

            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new SimpleInjectorWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
            AutomapperConfig.SetCreateMaps();
        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compilation Error when change .Net framework from 4.5.2 to 4.5 in VS 2015 Community edition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33317074/compilation-error-when-change-net-framework-from-4-5-2-to-4-5-in-vs-2015-commun)

Answer (score 0):

Check for the "System.Web.Http" DLL in the bin folder of your source code deployed on IIS.
It is responsible for the Class & associated methods.

Comment: it is there. tnx